# Put the domain user in login screen

Tags: user-account, login-screen, domain

Having done the domain binding, I need to log in with the domain user without entering the user every time. This is because I should type "domainname\user" each time and this is not very fast.
Is it possible to enter only the password and have the domain user already present in the login screen as it already happens with local accounts?